# Getting "Timeout Error" while doing FTP to server in VB6 using Inet control

Tags: ftp, vb6, winscp-net

I am able to **FTP using WinSCP client from my local desktop.
When i am trying to do it through code(VB6) I am getting timeout error every time**.
The same code works on server when deployed.So my question is:

> 1.> Am I missing some network setting which needs to be done?
>
> 2.> If yes then how come I am able to do successful FTP using WinSCP?
>
> ```
>   Inet2.URL = strImaging_Login
>
>   Inet2.Execute , "dir ./ImagesStaging/" & strImages_Folder_Name & "*"
>
>   Do While Inet2.StillExecuting = True
>         DoEvents
>   Loop
> ```

Comment: Poss UAC or similar authorisation issue. Show your VB6 code for the FTP connection.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine in servers for serveral years. When i make changes in the code and deploy it in server, it works like a charm.
I suppose i am missing some network setup in my local machine.
But then i am able to do FTP through WinSCP from same local machine.

Comment: To get a wider audience you could produce a cut-down test case in vbscript then edit the question to include the vbscript tag. I think the issue you face is possibly more about the user context of the exe than the specific tech being used.

Comment: @SumanGeorge: are you using PASV in WinSCP? Plese tell us your WinSCP settings.